# <div> fails to fill the page background properly

Tags: html, css, background

I have a `<div>` **positioning issue** on single-page web design. To be more specific — I can't find a way to fill the background properly, using the `<div>`s.

For some reason, the `<div>`s won't fill the background as I want — the background always stays visible (on left/right and top/bottom sides of the `<div>`s).

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- My entire page is a single-page website. The page is composed of 5 rectangle `<div>`s, "touching" each other in a vertical fashion (0 pixels of background between them). **I don't want the background to be visible at any part of the page**.
- I want the **top** `<div>` to fill the **upper** part of the screen ("touch" the browser's upper menu) and the **right/left** sides.
- I want each one of the 3 middle `<div>`s to "touch" the **left and right** sides of the screen (and of course touch the two `<div>`s above and below, without any space between them [no background seen]).
- I want the **bottom** `<div>` to fill the **lower** part of the screen ("touch" the browser's lower menu) and the **right/left** sides.

I've tried to change the `position` value on the CSS part. The outcome was always a "twisted" version of the page.

---

My **HTML** code:

```
<div id="page1" align="center">
    <a id="about"></a>
</div>
<div id="page2">
    <a id="portfolio"></a>
</div>
<div id="page3">
    <a id="Dream"></a>
</div>
<div id="page4">
    <a id="contact"></a>
</div>
<div id="page5">
    <a id="Love"></a>
</div>
```

My **CSS** code:

```
#page1{
    height : 1000px;
    background-color: #4c3719;
}
#page2{
  height : 1000px;
    background-color: #9a8479;
} 
#page3{
    height : 1000px;
    background-color: #ddbad8;
}
#page4{
    height : 1000px;
    background-color: #ddd28d;
}
#page5{
    height : 1000px;
    background-color: #ed9aa9;
}
```

---

[image: I've marked with red color the background popping out on the sides]

Comment: Have you set the margins on the `body` to zero? Use a reset css...

Comment: ...also `align` is no longer used in CSS like that.

Comment: margins is not a good solution because it is not generic (the maegins value has to be different on different devices). And the 'align' is used in the HTML and not CSS section..

Comment: Resetting margin on the body is absolutely standard. Also The `<div>` align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead is what I was trying to say.

Comment: Reset css - see http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Reset CSS can help me with the issue I'm facing here? Thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely, I don't know of **any** developer who doesn't use one. They're are many different varieties and most CSS frameworks will include one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write before all CSS code this

```
* {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0
}
```

If I correctly understand this may help